# AngularJS - watch is not working on variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This code is not working and I can't tell why.

HTML

```
<select id="provincia" class="form-control" ng-model="ciudades" ng-options="provincia for (provincia, ciudades) in provincias">
 <option ng-model="valor_ciudad" value=''>Elegir</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
    $scope.$watch('ciudades', function(newval, oldval){
        debugger;
        if (newval){
            $scope.prov = newval;
        }
    });
```

What do I want to do? I am trying to get the value picked by user because the variable ciudades has an array of values.

```
$scope.provincias = {Florida:['Miami', 'Orlando']}
```

If the user picks Florida, then $scope.ciudades will be ['Miami', 'Orlando']. What I need to know is if the user choose Florida or another city. (.watch didn't work, not even stopping on debugger)

Did I make myself clear?

Comment: Better to use `ng-change` for that [Read this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) (_Scope $watch Performance Considerations_)

Comment: You could set the objectEquality to true. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the 'Florida' key as your key and value and set to the `prov` directly with the select's ng-model then, listen for `prov` changes and set `ciudades` based on the chosen key:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $compile, $timeout) { 
  $scope.provincias = {
    Florida: ['Miami', 'Orlando']
   };
  $scope.$watch('prov', function(newval, oldval){
    $scope.ciudades = $scope.provincias[newval];
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <select ng-model="prov" ng-options="key as key for (key, value) in provincias">
    <option ng-model="valor_ciudad" value=''>Elegir</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  $scope.prov: {{prov}}<br>
  $scope.ciudades: {{ciudades}}<br>
</div>
```

Comment: You are the man! I still .watch not working on my code by I used ng-change and your code and it's working. Thanks